# Should we have a new reason for close votes which encompasses a case where the question is so sloppy that it obviously contradicts itself?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Should we have a new reason for close votes which encompasses a case where the question is so sloppy that it obviously contradicts itself?

I don't see that any of the existing reasons to close encompasses such a case.

Or is the more appropriate thing to do just to downvote or comment?

Example of such a question -- [Why do fighter jets land faster than Jumbo commercial aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16427/why-do-fighter-jets-land-faster-than-jumbo-commercial-aircraft?rq=1)

Comment: You might want to find a better example than a 5-year-old question that was well-received.

Comment: @fooot -- Why?  Is it not obvious that that question contradicts itself?  If your point is essentially "No, because some questions turn out to be well received even if they contradict themselves", then I guess I chose the perfect example, because it allowed you to make your point.  You could consider making that an actual answer rather just a comment.  I would still say that the question contradicts itself and would vote to close were there a valid reason.

Comment: I just think you'd want to find a question that was not well received but left open because we didn't have a good reason for closing it.

Comment: (Never mind, I fully agree that "needs details or clarity" is an adequate reason to vote to close a question that obviously contradicts itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think the question contradicts itself, the closest reason for closing would seem to be "needs details or clarity."